# converting type "string" to base64 with php

Tags: php, base64, xml-rpc

This is jointly an xmlrpc question. I have a string of data coming in from a .wav file. I read the file in, with `file_get_contents()` then I have to submit that information to an xmlrpc server (which I did not create). It takes the .wav audio data in base64. I have tried using `base64_encode()`, but that also returns the "string" type. I thought that maybe [This php guide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-set-type.php) on `xmlrpc_set_type` would help, but this returns an object containing an array that contains a base64 encoded string.

Is there a way to set the string that I am working with as type base64?

this is what I have so far, that is creating errors:

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents('myfile.wav', NULL, NULL, 44));
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('service',array('AudioData'=>$data));
```

I have tried this as well:

```
$data = file_get_contents('myfile.wav', NULL, NULL, 44);
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('service',array('AudioData'=>xmlrpc_set_type($data, 'base64')));
```

This is the response I get:

```
["faultCode"]=> int(0) ["faultString"]=> string(155) "request contains string value where base64 expected
```

## EDIT:

I am aware that base64 is not a type. Obviously the server I am using will not except a string of base64 encoded data, so my question is how to make that work.

Comment: There is not data type base64 in PHP. Base64 is a string representation of binary data.

Comment: I sorta figured, It makes sense, but when I pass it strings of base64 encoded data, the web-service freaks out because it's a string?

Comment: Hmm that error is definately weird since base64 encoding will always come out as string. I am guessing it cannot recognise your bas64 string? Are you sure it is your end causing the problem?

Comment: It might be the web-service's end. I suppose php does not have a way to represent this data in anything but a string?

Comment: If the set type does not work I would bet with no, really the webservice should be able to decode the string, judge it calculates correct to bas64 and use that as a validator, it could be doing that and that's what's giving you the error, some how your string is getting mangled, however I am unsure. I mean set type returns an array because if how it needs to define the var so I am not sure why that wouldnt work either, however the PHP doc doesnt like that function very much as you've probably noticed

Comment: Reading it more closely, it clearly takes the set_type function server side else it would not be saying you got a string, so I don't think there is any problem with the type being defined I think the problem is with the error message. It is a vague and stupid message

Comment: I agree, and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of a knowledge base on xml-rpc function calls within php. I would think that the web-service would be expecting a string either way, I'm not sure what the developer did when he created that server. But if the only way to represent this data is in a string, I'm going to have to change the web-service to a string. Thanks!

Comment: try using fopen to open your wav file instead of file_get_contents, from php docs :  "file_get_contents — Reads entire file into a string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xmlrpc_set_type` function can be used to "mark" a value as being of a specific type (base64 or datetime) in a XML-RPC request. It returns a boolean indicating if the operation was successful.

Basically, what happens is that the value is wrapped in a standard PHP class object along with its type and the variable passed as a reference to `xmlrpc_set_type` holds this object instead of the original raw value.

When calling `xmlrpc_encode_request`, the same variable previously passed as a reference to `xmlrpc_set_type` in order to declare the value type, should be embedded in a `$params` array passed as second argument.

Please note, these functions are still considered as experimental and should be used with much care.

Example:

```
<?php

$method = 'app.service';

// $value contains raw content
xmlrpc_set_type($value, 'base64'); 

// $request contains base64 encoded content
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request($method, array($value);
```